# how to findall with python regex and preserve group numbers on matches

Tags: python, regex

I feel that this *must* have been asked somewhere else already, but I cannot find it!

I have a regex that has nested brackets (see below). I need to match ALL occurrences of it in a line and then do something with the pieces. However, I cannot figure out how to reference specific groups from my regex.

Specifically, this is my regex:

```
(([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_\+\-\.]*\.)+\s*[a-zA-Z]{2,6})
```

I actually don't care about preserving the contents of the inner brackets I just want to get all the matches for the outer one.

If I use "match" I get one instance and can reference by using the Match Object. However, when I do findall, it does not return Match Objects, it only returns a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for `re.finditer()`:

```
import re

a = 'foo 123 blah 234 xxx 655'
for m in re.finditer(r'(\d+)', a):
  print m.group(1)
```